# Circle group $S^1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, visualization

Can someone describe the circle group $S^1$ in a easily understandable way? Are elements in $S^1$ in the form of $e^{2i\theta\pi}$? What does this look like pictorially? Doesn't necessarily need a graph but maybe at least describe it? 
Appreciated!

Comment: It's... a circle. The group operation is multiplication like you describe. I'm not quite sure what your question is asking. Do you know that complex numbers have that representation, and that $e$ to an imaginary power is norm 1?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure about e to an imaginary number power. I will look into that, thank you

Comment: Instead of considering elements of the group as $e$ to an imaginary power, simply consider them to be angles. Then the group operation is addition of angles.

Comment: Oooooor consider them to be the real numbers modulo $1$, or modulo $2\pi$.
Or rigid rotations of a circle. Pictorically it's just a circle.